# How to distribute a Python package where import name is different than project name using Hatch?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, hatch

I am trying to package my project in order to upload it in PyPI. I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── docs
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── package_name
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── data.json
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   ├── utils.py
└── tests
```

My package is in under `src` named `src/package_name`.

The `pyproject.toml` has the following lines:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "project_name"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [{name = "Foo Bar"}]
license = {text = "GPL-3.0-only"}
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://example.com"
```

I want a user to be able to perform the installation as:

```bash
pip install project_name
```

but use the code as:

```py
>>> from package_name import x
```

Is there any way to achieve this with [Hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/)? I have read the [Build-instructions](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/build/) but can't find how.

**Note**

I have tried the following:

```bash
python3 -m build
python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
pip install --upgrade -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ project_name
```

The problem is when I type:

```py
>>> import package_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name'
```

I searched into `path/to/site-packages` but only `path/to/site-packages/project_name-0.0.1.dist-info` is there. Any ideas?

Tried to solve my problem based on this [Tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

The reason I used Hatch is because it was presented in the tutorial. Αn alternative solution (using also `pyproject.toml` with different backend) is also appreciated.

**Edit**

I have updated the directory structure as proposed in the comments.

Comment: What is there in `src`? I recommend you update the question to show the file and directory structure in `src`, in particular the location of the `__init__.py` files if any. -- You can also read this part of the hatch doc: [file selection](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#file-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem by simply switching to `setuptools` as backend and modifying the `pyproject.toml` as following:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "package_name.__version__"}

[project]
name = "package_name"
dynamic = ["version"]

authors = [{name = "Foo Bar"}]
license = {text = "GPL-3.0-only"}
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"

classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://example.com""
```

My solution is based on the [setuptools Documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html).